# Category with binary biproducts but no zero morphism

Tags: ct.category-theory, duality

> Is there a category with binary biproducts but no zero morphism?

I'm wondering if the definition of [biproducts](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/biproduct) as objects that are simultaneously products and coproducts that obey some identities on the projections/injections is 'different' than the definition involving a zero object. Whenever a zero object exists the definitions are trivially equivalent, and an empty biproduct is a zero object, so we would need a category with binary biproducts but no nullary ones. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Karvonen has an [article on arXiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.06488.pdf) showing that if a category has all binary biproducts (using the alternative definition Tom mentioned) then it has zero morphisms (Corollary 3.3).

Comment: @AliCaglayan Thank you, if you'd like to post that as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Karvonen has an [article on arXiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.06488.pdf) showing that if a category has all binary biproducts (using the alternative definition Tom mentioned) then it has zero morphisms (Corollary 3.3).

Answer (score 5):

There is a definition of biproduct that mentions neither zero objects nor zero morphisms, equivalent to the standard definition when zero objects/morphisms do exist. This definition is due to Martti Karvonen, and can be found in Section 5.2 of his [thesis](https://era.ed.ac.uk/handle/1842/35867).

Here it is (his Definition 5.8): for objects $A$ and $B$ of a category, a **biproduct** of $A$ and $B$ consists of an object $A \oplus B$ and morphisms $p_A, p_B, i_A, i_B$ such that $(A \oplus B, p_A, p_B)$ is a product, $(A \oplus B, i_A, i_B)$ is a coproduct, and the following equations hold:
$$
p_A i_A = 1_A, \quad p_B i_B = 1_B, \quad i_A p_A i_B p_B = i_B p_B i_A p_A. 
$$
To explain the last equation: the first two equations imply that $i_A p_A$ and $i_B p_B$ are idempotents, and the last one states that these idempotents commute.

Comment: I think this is stated in the link given in the question - the question seems to be about whether there's a real difference. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi You are correct, this definition is given in the link in my post and I was curious about the 'difference' between the two. The comment by Ali Caglayan seems to answer the question by saying there is no difference, at least in the finite case.

Comment: Ah, OK. I didn't click the link to the nLab entry on biproducts, so I didn't know it mentioned Karvonen's work.